# Is it possible to send custom currency type to Paypal using PayPal PayFlow?

Tags: magento, paypal, payment-gateway, checkout, currency

Is there any way to send Paypay custom currency type other than base currency ? Currently we have 2 store views for US and CANADA and we would like to accept payment in the native currency.

US store funds will be received in USD currency and CA store funds will be received in CAD currency irrespective of the base currency. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use different currencies for Magento payflow. When you are sending data to payflow using setexpresscheckout method then there is a field named "Currency". You can set value to USD or CAD as per the respective store.